# Linear Inhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using a Bernoulli substitution, at what point does the differential equation $dx/dt = x + x^{2020}cos(t)$ become a linear inhomogeneous?

Comment: I tried to format but couldn't get the power to work

Comment: Exponents must be enclosed in braces { }.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx}{dt}-x&=&x^{2020}\cos(t)\\
x^{-2020}\frac{dx}{dt}-x^{-2019}&=&\cos(t)
\end{eqnarray}

Let $u=x^{-2019}$. Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=-2019x^{-2020}\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

\begin{eqnarray}
x^{-2020}\frac{dx}{dt}-x^{-2019}&=&\cos(t)\\
-2019x^{-2020}\frac{dx}{dt}+2019x^{-2019}&=&-2019\cos(t)\\
\frac{du}{dt}+2019u=-2019\cos(t)
\end{eqnarray}

This is where it becomes linear non-homogeneous.

Comment: thank you, this is what I assumed to be the case. From here I was told to use the method of variation to solve this DE but the constant as a function of t I calulated was zero, does this make sense?

Comment: The constant would depend upon the initial value if one were given.